# Socket.io on client side delay

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-chrome, firefox, socket.io

We have problems with working together on the same page, everything works fine on Chrome, Safari except Firefox. If we typing (fast) on Chrome and we watch on Firefox what we typing on Chrome, we see a very large delay on Firefox. It seems as if the browser crashes or having a memory problem.
If we typing fast on Firefox and watch on Chrome, we see everything directly changes on the screen.

For working together we use a nodeJS server and socket.io.

Comment: What versions of Socket.io and Firefox?

Comment: Socket.io = 1.3.5
Firefox = 37
We use also angular 1.3.14 and Laravel 5